# How to use a microphone with Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, audio

I have a project which consist to control the Raspberry with voice.

I use an adapter (Logitech): [Google "microphone  for raspberry" search](https://www.google.com/search?q=micro%20for%20raspberry&client=ubuntu&hs=W1D&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv0avJv-nMAhVHshQKHRnqC-QQ_AUICSgD&biw=1301&bih=673#channel=fs&tbm=isch&q=microphone%20%20for%20raspberry&imgrc=8KBvXdzBNhp0JM%3A).

What configuration do I need to make it work?

Comment: Don't forget to enter the description here!

Answer (score 1):

If the adapter you mention is a usb sound card, it will work. Alternatively you can also use a GPIO header based sound card, such as [one of these](http://elinux.org/index.php?title=RPi_Expansion_Boards#Sound).

To record, try installing and using "audacity". Or if you want to use voice commands, [try to use one of these already existing softwares to do that](http://diyhacking.com/best-voice-recognition-software-for-raspberry-pi/). This linke discusses the following 3 softwares which may be of interest to you :
Jasper – Voice Recognition Software.
Raspberry Pi Voice Recognition by Oscar Liang.
Raspberry Pi Voice Control by Steven Hickson.

Comment: Could you please include some specific detail in your answer, link only answers are generally discouraged.

Comment: Hi Darth, thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately in this situation, I don't quite see that your feedback is relevant. I have done my best to suggest other means to get microphone input to the Pi. In a second link, I have mentioned where to start with voice control of the Pi.